# Summary chart for three categorical variables

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data

Can a single chart be used to summarize three categorical variables, much like a [Marimekko Chart](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=marimekko%20chart) can be used to summarize two? Obviously, a set of Marimekko Charts could be displayed in a [small multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple) fashion, but I am looking for a single chart instead. And if 3D rendering is necessary, it should not require any rotation or zooming for the full dataset to be comprehended at a glance. And to be clear, the three categorical variables are the independent variables, while the chart is depicting them with a single dependent variable, which is assumed to be numerical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marimekko plots are a subset of [mosaic plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot). You can interweave in third or fourth variable. There is a nice example on wikipedia for the titanic data. The vcd package in R can make these for you, and a variation called a double-decker plot. Also the package prodplots adds a formal structure for defining plots for categorical variables. Another package called extract has a variety of tools for categorical data. There are also other approaches like hammock plots, an adaptation of parallel coordinate plots, are available in ggparallel.